# <cfsharepoint> Unable to read WSDL from URL: ... Error: 401 Unauthorized.

Tags: sharepoint, coldfusion

I try to use the tag  in Coldfusion 9 to upload some files in my sharepoint but there is the probleme with that simple code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>cfsharepoint Views Example</title> 
</head> 

<body> 

<cfoutput> 
Getting the list collection<br /> 

<cfsharepoint action="getlistcollection" domain="sharepoint/it" username="username" password="pwd" name="result"/> 


result.ResultFlag: #result.ResultFlag#<br><br> 

</cfoutput> 

</body> 
</html>
```

When I start my page, it says :

> Unable to read WSDL from URL: 
>   sharepoint/it/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl.
>   Error: 401 Unauthorized.

How can I fix it ?

Thank you !

Comment: Sounds like the credentials you're passing are incorrect. Have you tried the url in your browser with the same credentials?

Comment: Yes, I have got the access to sharepoint/it/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl in my web browser.

Comment: @Kruhk - did you try to access the URL from the browser on the server that is running ColdFusion?

Comment: @Miguel-F Yes, I have the access too on the server where CF is installed.

Answer (score 0):

The `cfsharepoint` tag only works with basic authentication, so no NTLM (HTTPS) can be used.

This is a major drawback for the tag and in most large organizations goes completely against their security policies.

If you only have basic authentication you could also try and prefix your username with the domain e.g. `username="sharepoint\username"` I had to do that with one of the projects I worked on.